# Thunderbird/Enigmail: problem with colors

Tags: thunderbird

When I decrypt an encrypted email in Thunderbird (using the Enigmail extension), the enigmail header is displayed in very strange colors, very light green background with white text. This makes the text unreadable.

[image]

I am wondering where these colors come from. I have no such colors defined in my Thunderbird. My Thunderbird is using system colors (defined in LXDE/Openbox).

Is there any way to change these color to something sane? Such as the text from white to black, so that I can actually see what is displayed there?

## UPDATE:

I have made some progress. According to [Enigmail code](http://sourceforge.net/p/enigmail/source/ci/master/tree/ui/skin/tb-linux/enigmail.css), the element that I need to change is this one:

```
.enigmailHeaderBoxLabelSignatureOk {
    background-color:#ccffcc;
color: black;
}
```

However, when I add the following into my `$HOME/.icedove/XXXXXXXX.default/chrome/userContent.css`, it has no effect. It still shows the default color (`ccffcc`).

```
enigmailHeaderBoxLabelSignatureOk {
background-color:#FF0000 ! important;
color: black ! important;
}
```

I don't have much experience with changing Thunderbird appearance with `userContent.css`. Can somebody please help?

Comment: Is that literally the contents of the file?  You're missing the first dot (`.`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. Just insert the code into your `userChrome.css` (not `userContent.css`) and also don't forget to add the dot at the beginning, as referenced in the link you provided.

Thus, this should be in your `userChrome.css`.

```
.enigmailHeaderBoxLabelSignatureOk {
background-color:#FF0000 ! important;
color: black ! important;
}
```

That works for me on my machine

Answer (score 1):

I think the white text is defined in your GTK configuration. White text is likely if you have a dark theme installed.

If you do not wish to change your GTK theme, installing a theme for Thunderbird can solve your problem. I personally use [TT DeepDark](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/tt-deepdark/?src=cb-dl-users), but other ones are available [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/complete-themes/).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I am happy with my current Thunderbird colors/theme and I don't want to install any theme. Is there no way to change just the color for Enigmail?

Comment: Well, if Enigmail doesn't provide any color preferences, then the only possible solution I can think of is to edit the source code.